# Jquery datatable add rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, datatable

I have a datatable in my page initiated like below:

```
var dataSet = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Bennett Weimann", "email": "jtremblay@example.com" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Bennett Weimann", "email": "buckridge.orin@example.com" }
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', title: 'Id' },
            { data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
            { data: 'email', title: 'Email' },
        ],
    });
});
```

Additionally I have a button which makes an AJAX post request, in the answer I get a JSON

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Bennett Weimann","email":"jtremblay@example.com"},
{"id":2,"name":"Bennett Weimann","email":"buckridge.orin@example.com"}]
```

If I try to add the response like below, I get an error

```
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        table = $('#example').DataTable();
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(response);
        table.draw();

    });
```

Error is

> "DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/4"](http://datatables.net/tn/4%22)

However if I copy and paste the response manually, it has no issue whatsoever.

```
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.clear();
table.rows.add([
    {"id":1,"name":"Bennett Weimann","email":"jtremblay@example.com"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Bennett Weimann","email":"buckridge.orin@example.com"}
]);
table.draw();

});
```

Any help appreciated what could cause such error?

Comment: I don't know how you are executing your `request` (can you show us?) - but are you sure the JSON response is an unnamed array `[ { ... }, { ... } ]` and not an object `{ "foo": [ { ... }, { ... } ] }`? Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 1):

I must have been tired.. after a sleep I could see that I was passing an object instead of an array.
I am using php as a backend, if I create an array like

```
    $data = array([
        "id"  => 1,
        "name" => "foo",
        "email" => "bar"
    ]);

    return $data;
```

and passing the response it works like charm

```
 request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        table = $('#example').DataTable();
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(response);
        table.draw();

    });
```